Question regarding the order of transactions
If someone makes a transaction it is first sent to the mempool. The validator picks up a number of transaction to be added to the next block. Does the validator select x transactions and then add them one by one in that order, regardless of what new transaction may come to the mempool even if the gas fee is higher, or does the validator take one transaction from the mempool, adds it, then looks again at the mempool and adds another one and so on?


Does the validator select x transactions and then add them one by one in that order

No. Validators include transactions in the order which allows them to extract as much as possible money from the blockchain users, including through malicious means. This is called MEV.
Because of malicious validators, most of Ethereum transactions go through private mempools.

let's say i monitor the reserves of a liquidity pool and a transaction makes a swap. do i see the change in reserves after that transaction or do i see it only after the whole block has been added?

Blocks are either fully or not at all. Only the validator who produces to block can see changes after each individual transaction and this is how they abuse their power.

this means we can't know the exact amount of reserves of a liquidity pool at any given moment?

There is no moment or time for individual transactions, only for blocks. The only valid timestamp to known exact amount of reserves at a liquidity pool is the block number, end of the block, for an external observer.

If you are not familiar how blockchains opreate please take a look at this first.

i understand that, however when i read them at the end of the block there could be a swap already in the mempool so when i read the reserves and want to submit a swap myself it will be too late so i will not execute the swap with the reserves i read

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"it will be too late" that's how the speed of light works. Not all computers around the world can be synchronous at the same time. There is nothing you can do except deal with it.
